# Convert time over 60 seconds into minutes and seconds in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my spreadsheet, I have results to calculate the average of my result of endurance, which shows as: 2.71 min. But that is wrong to have 2 minutes and 71 seconds.

How can I convert 2.71 minutes into 3 minutes 11 seconds?

Comment: I think this is a simple modulo question, 71 = 11+60 (2m 71s = 3m 11s). This question belongs on StackOverflow, though.

Comment: @jornane -- no it doesn't. This question is a perfect fit for SuperUser, because it is about solving a problem with specific software, in this case, MS Excel. Although it may be possible to abstract the underlying calculations into a product-independent format, that does not help with applying the formula to the product in question.

Comment: Shouldn't 2.71 min be 2 min + 60*0.71=42.6 s?

Comment: So, you're using "2.71" to represent 2 minutes ***and 71 seconds***?  And you're treating values like that as numbers (rather than strings)?  That seems to be very risky.  OK, 40 seconds + 40 seconds = 0.40 + 0.40 = 0.80 = 80 seconds, but what about 50 seconds + 50 seconds = 0.50 + 0.50 = 1 = ???

Comment: 2.71mins ; 2 = 60*2 = 120secs and 71mins = 60secs = 1min and 11 seconds and the result should be 3mins and 11 seconds;

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The formula in cell B1 is

```
=TIME(0,INT(A1),MOD(A1,1)*100)
```

Format the cell with custom format `mm:ss` or `hh:mm:ss` if you want to show hours in the time stamp.

Comment: I had to format as `mm:ss`

Comment: Sorry, yes. that's the one. I'll correct my post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Other solution was to covert all my numbers like 2.70; 2.20mins;
   3.00; in seconds with this formula:

> =MID(A1,1,1)*60+MID(A1,3,3)

- A1 = 2.70 (numbers formate as text, to show the zero like this 2.70
  if is a numbers show 2.7)
  then make the average of the seconds and then convert seconds in
  minutes and seconds:

> =INT(A2/60)&"' "&ROUND(MOD(A2,60),0)&"”"

- „A2” = average of seconds (eg. 189)

RESULT is:3'9"